# qml canvas, context 2d is reset after every calling js function from c++

Tags: c++, qt, canvas, qml, elf

I have Qt Quick Controls 2 Application. In main.qml I have besides other things canvas in scroll view:

```
Rectangle {
    id: graph
    width: mainArea.width / 3 - 14;
    height: mainArea.height - 20;
    ScrollView{
        anchors.fill: parent;
        Canvas {
            id:canvasGraph;
            width: graph.width;
            height: graph.height;
            property bool paintB: false;

            property string colorRect: "#FFFF40";
            property string name: "ELF header";

            property int paintX: 0;
            property int paintY: 0;

            property int widthP: 160;
            property int heightP: 30;

            property int textX: (paintX + (widthP / 2)) - 15/*func return int length of text*/;
            property int textY: (paintY + (heightP / 2)) + 3;

            onPaint:{
                if (paintB){
                    var ctx = canvasGraph.getContext('2d');
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.font = "normal 12px serif";
                    ctx.fillStyle = colorRect;
                    ctx.strokeRect(paintX, paintY, widthP, heightP);
                    ctx.fillRect(paintX, paintY, widthP, heightP);
                    ctx.strokeText("ELF header", textX, textY);
                    ctx.closePath();
                    ctx.save();
                }
            }
            MouseArea{
                id: canvasArea;
                anchors.fill: parent;
                onPressed: {
                   paint(mouseX,mouseY,"aaa",1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At first I tried draw into canvas by js function, here:

```
function paint(x, y, name, type) {
    canvasGraph.paintB = true;
    canvasGraph.paintX = x;
    canvasGraph.paintY = y;
    canvasGraph.requestPaint();
}
```

This function was called by pressing mouse on canvas. It works good, it draw rectangles, one by one. But only one problem was, that after resizing app window, all rectangles except last one get lost. But it's not primary problem, because it works and this promblem I could resolve later.

For drawing chart I need C++ library (ELFIO, for reading ELF files). So in main.cpp I have two object. First allows me call from main.qml functions of some C++ class. Second allows me calling js functions from C++. Here is main.cpp:

```
QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

QScopedPointer<elfFile> elfFileObj(new elfFile); 

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));

engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("elfFileObj", elfFileObj.data()); //this is for calling c++ from qml

QObject *rof = engine.rootObjects().first(); 
elfFileObj.data()->rofS = rof; //this one is for calling js func from c++
return app.exec();
```

How you can see, reading ELF files is manage from object *elfFileObj*, where is public variable which holds loaded ELF file and variable *rofS* which hold object for access to main.qml to js functions.

In *elfFileObj* is *Q_INVOKABLE int loadELF(QString fileName);* where Q_INVOKABLE is macro, which ensure, that this function is possible call from qml file. Function:

```
int elfFile::loadELF(QString fileName)
{
    string fileNameReal = (fileName).toStdString().substr(7);
    if (!reader.load(fileNameReal.c_str())){
         return -1;
    }

    QVariant x(30);
    QVariant y(10);
    QVariant name("ELF header");
    QVariant type(1);

    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(rofS, "paint", Q_ARG(QVariant,x), Q_ARG(QVariant,y), Q_ARG(QVariant,name), Q_ARG(QVariant,type));
    y = QVariant(40);
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(rofS, "paint", Q_ARG(QVariant,x), Q_ARG(QVariant,y), Q_ARG(QVariant,name), Q_ARG(QVariant,type));
}
```

I try draw two rectangles, one by one. *QMetaObject::invokeMethod* should call js functions, which draw rectangle on (x,y). Other args are in this moment unusable.

**Main problem:** It draw rectangles on canvas, but after every call by invokeMethod is canvas cleared. So on the canvas always stay only last one rectangle.

Have somebody any idea, how to save actual state of canvas? Thanks for any help.
It isn't pretty code, but it's my first experience with qml.

Answer (score 0):

The canvas, being an imperative drawing API, just has a dumb buffer of pixel data. It has no concept of objects like rectangles or anything else once the draw call has finished. As such, you are responsible for everything that it displays via your onPaint handler. It does not clear the canvas content from one frame to another (as an optimization), but it will (by necessity) clear it when you resize the window, as it has to allocate a differently sized buffer.

You can see this behaviour here:

```
import QtQuick 2.6

Canvas {
    id: canvasGraph;
    width: 500
    height: 500
    property int paintY: 10;

    onPaint:{
        var ctx = canvasGraph.getContext('2d');
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.font = "normal 12px serif";
        ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
        ctx.strokeRect(10, paintY, 160, 30);
        ctx.fillRect(10, paintY, 160, 30);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.save();
    }

    Timer {
        interval: 16
        running: true
        repeat: true
        onTriggered: {
            canvasGraph.requestPaint();
            canvasGraph.paintY += 10
            if (canvasGraph.paintY > canvasGraph.height)
                canvasGraph.paintY = 10
        }
    }
}
```

Try run this example with qmlscene and resize the window. You'll notice that all content is cleared on resize, except that one single rectangle that it draws.

So, if you want all your rectangles to be retained, then you need to paint them in the onPaint handler each time (and make use of clearRect or some other method to fill the background to get rid of stuff that doesn't belong there anymore, if you are moving stuff around or making them invisible).

On the other hand, I can't directly explain why invokeMethod would be causing it to clear, as you haven't really presented enough code. It may be that it's resizing the canvas (causing the buffer to reallocate, and be cleared). Either way, given the above, I'd say that it isn't all that relevant.

After all this, while I don't have full background over what you are making, I'd suggest that perhaps Canvas might not be the best tool to do what you want. You might want to look into QQuickPaintedItem instead, or (better still) composing your scene using a custom QQuickItem which positions other QQuickItems (or QSGNodes). Canvas (and QQuickPaintedItem) while easy to use, are not especially performant.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't solved this problem. I just stop using QML and return to use just Qt. It helps me.